# Jasmine javascript : How to check response contain something?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, javascript-objects

How to check response contain postText with wuihduwih and userId: '60f469cf784379051298e96d'

here is the response  :
`({ id: '612bf0792ca01806398da2d6', data: Object({ createdOn: '2021-08-29T20:39:21.445Z', lastUpdatedBy: null, userId: '60f469cf784379051298e96d', displayName: 'Nadia', postText: 'wuihduwih', postImages: [  ], pluginInstance: Object({ pluginInstanceId: '1627334094776-047554258642281355', pluginInstanceTitle: 'communityFeedPlugin' }), isPublic: false, _buildfire: Object({ index: Object({ array1: [ Object({ string1: 'userId_60f469cf784379051298e96d' }), Object({ string1: 'displayName_nadia' }), Object({ string1: 'pluginTitle_communityfeedplugin' }), Object({ string1: 'isPublic_0' }) ] }) }) }), tag: 'posts' })`

tried the following but failed :

````
        Posts.addPost({postText :'wuihduwih'},(err,resp) => {
          expect(resp).toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
              postText :'wuihduwih'
            }));
          done();
        }); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jasmine [introductory page](https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html), `toContain` "works for finding an item in an Array" and "also works for finding a substring". They make no mention of using `toContain` to find objects within objects.

If the response's structure is always the same/the fields `userId` and `postText` are always in the same spot, you can just do:

```js
expect(resp.data.postText).toEqual('wuihduwih');
```

and

```js
expect(resp.data.hasOwnProperty('userId')).toBe(true);
```

or, if the `userId` never changes:

```js
expect(resp.data.hasOwnProperty('userId')).toEqual('60f469cf784379051298e96d');
```

Based on the same introductory page, you can also use `objectContaining`, as you've tried, but combined with `toEqual` instead of `toContain`:

```js
expect(resp.data).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
  postText: 'wuihduwih',
  userId: '60f469cf784379051298e96d'
}));
```

Note that I pass in `resp.data`, not just `resp`. The referenced page doesn't say whether it works for nested objects.

Comment: did not work https://share.getcloudapp.com/E0ujArE7

Comment: Judging by your screenshot, you still use `toContain`. Did you not copy and paste my code?

Answer (score 0):

what if I want to validate a result from an array response !

`({ id: '612d56952ca01806398dac1f', lastUpdated: '2021-08-30T22:07:17.099Z', userToken: 'public', data: Object({ createdOn: '2021-08-30T22:07:16.916Z', lastUpdatedBy: null, userId: '60f469cf784379051298e96d', displayName: 'Nadia', postText: 'post text sample', postImages: 'image test', pluginInstance: Object({ pluginInstanceId: '1627334094776-047554258642281355', pluginInstanceTitle: 'communityFeedPlugin' }), isPublic: true, _buildfire: Object({ index: Object({ array1: [ Object({ string1: 'userId_60f469cf784379051298e96d' }), Object({ string1: 'displayName_nadia' }), Object({ string1: 'pluginTitle_communityfeedplugin' }), Object({ string1: 'isPublic_1' }) ] }) }) }) }), Object({ id: '612d564dfabce50627bdb5db', lastUpdated: '2021-08-30T22:06:05.699Z', userToken: 'public', data: Object({ createdOn: '2021-08-30T22:06:05.500Z', lastUpdatedBy: null, userId: '60f469cf784379051298e96d', displayName: 'Nadia', postText: 'post text sample', postImages: 'image test', pluginInstance: Object ...`

tried the following but did not work :

```
it('Get all posts' , function(done){
    Posts.getPosts('publicPosts' ,(err,resp) =>{
        expect(resp).toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
            id: '612d50bafabce50627bdb538',
            postText:'post text sample',
            userId: '60f469cf784379051298e96d',
            isPublic: true
          }));
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Suggestions or queries regarding asked questions must be maintained in the comment section. Answer post meant for solving the question only

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.